# Unable to connect to the server connecteX Error

Tags: virtualbox, kubectl, microk8s

I am using Microk8s on my local Windows 10 machine and am unable to get pods or use most of kubectl commands.

At the time of installation of microk8s, multipass selected VitrualBox for VM virtualization.

I get below error

```
C:\Users\owner>microk8s kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:16443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

VirtualBox Version 6.1
Ensured that multipass list shows that the VM is in running state.

There was a prior version of VitrualBox and minikube - both of which I have now un-installed and installed VirtualBox alone. Also cleaned up %USER_HOME%/.kube directory and %USER_HOME%/AppData/local/minikube & %USER_HOME%/AppData/local/VirtualBox folders too.

Comment: Can you add your kubeconfig file via setting KUBECONFIG env. var? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409025/docker-and-windows-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did

Comment: Thanks @Malgorzata. I verified the kubeconfig is the correct one and the current context shows up correct to be 'microk8s'. I also validated that the VirtualBox version is 6.1. However, I notice that there is another kubectl version on my machine due to an older minikube that I had uninstalled. I am seeing how to clean that up to see if that is cause for this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment and config files ? See: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4765